# Arduino TCNT1 to count clock cycles between interrupts?

Tags: arduino

I am new to Arduino programming and trying to use the arduino uno as a high resolution timer.  I would like to be able to count clock cycles at the full 16MHz rate between two rising edge interrupts.  I have some code that is functional using the micros() function which has 4 microsecond resolution, and I need better than that.  Here is an example code where I am trying to use micros() for the timing:

```
volatile int k = 0;
volatile float t1 = 0;
volatile float t2 = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), ISR1, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(3), ISR2, RISING);
}

void ISR2()
{
  k = 1;
  t1 = micros();
  Serial.println(1);
}

void ISR1()
{
  k = 2;
  t2 = micros();
  Serial.println(2);
}

void loop()
{
  if (t1 != 0 && t2 != 0) {
    if (t2 - t1 < 0) {
      t1 = 0;
      t2 = 0;
    }
    else {
      Serial.print("tdelta ");
      Serial.print(t2 - t1);
      t1 = 0;
      t2 = 0;
      Serial.println(0);
    }

    }
}
```

I realize that my micros timing is probably getting a bit offset by the interrupts, which may be an issue.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I think I want to use timer1 since it is 16 bit and my events should be fast enough to be completed before any overflow occurs.  I am hoping to find a simple way to set up tcnt1 to be 0 with the first interrupt and then count tcnt1 clock cycles until the second interrupt. I don't really even know how to read the values from tcnt1 though, so I have a ways to go.

I have searched for examples, but haven't really found one that seems appropriate.  Everything seems to be geared towards timer interrupts which I don't think is quite what I'm after.

I am probably lacking a lot of needed understanding to use this tcnt1 counter, but any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to work with timer registers directly. Look at manual for CPU which is used on your particular board. For mega it is ATmega2560-16AU. Timer register's name is TCNT1. You can store its value:

```
int t1;// declare global variable somewhere
t1 = TCNT1; //save timer value in ISRx interrupts
```

Be sure to setup prescaler value `TCCR1B.CSn` and handle timer overflow interrupt, else you will lose time data: `ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)`

As you can read here [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer1) precision of <1 uS can be reached.
[More info](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Timers-Arduino) of how to work directly with CPU timers registers.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the info!  Exactly what I was lacking!  Got it working.